# How to retrieve data of another user on firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Making a social network application, I put a setOnClickListener to an Image view containing a user profile image which redirects to a profile page that displays a read version of the user data when the image was clicked (data of user whose image has been clicked). I'm wanting to know how I could retrieve another user's information from a read view as another user. At the moment, the code is currently set to retrieving the username of the current user on a text view.

UserProfile.java

```
private TextView Profile_Username;

private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;

private String user_id;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

    Profile_Username = findViewById(R.id.profile_username);

    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


    firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful())
            {
                if (task.getResult().exists())
                {
                    String name = task.getResult().getString("name");


                    Profile_Username.setText(name);
                }
            }else {
                //Firebase exceptions
                String error = task.getException().getMessage();


            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: unfortunately no, worked around the problem with changing some functionalities @AlexMamo

Comment: Have you tried to use the same code but to change `user_id` with `firend_id`?